# Having trouble with finding a specific node using its attributes in xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms, attributes

I have the following `XML` file and want to find an element with a specific Attribute. What I wan tot find is looking for an attribute with `"Type" == "Billing"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrderNumber="99503" OrderDate="1999-10-20">
  <Address Type="Shipping">
    <Name>Ellen Adams</Name>
    <Street>123 Maple Street</Street>
    <City>Mill Valley</City>
    <State>CA</State>
    <Zip>10999</Zip>
    <Country>USA</Country>
  </Address>
  <Address Type="Billing">
    <Name>Tai Yee</Name>
    <Street>8 Oak Avenue</Street>
    <City>Old Town</City>
    <State>PA</State>
    <Zip>95819</Zip>
    <Country>USA</Country>
    <Address Type="Shipping">
        <Name>Ellen Adams</Name>
    </Address>
    <Address Type="transporting">
        <Name>Tai Yee</Name>
        <Street>8 Oak Avenue</Street>
    </Address>
  </Address>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

The problem is that here second `Address` node has some other inner nodes that would not be related to what I really wan to have. I mean attributes with the `Shipping` and `transporting` should not be in the out put. If I think of have only the following output what code would be desired?

```
<Address Type="Billing">
  <Name>Tai Yee</Name>
  <Street>8 Oak Avenue</Street>
  <City>Old Town</City>
  <State>PA</State>
  <Zip>95819</Zip>
  <Country>USA</Country>
</Address>
```

and the code which I have is:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("PurchaseOrder.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> address =
    from el in root.Elements("Address")
    where (string)el.Attribute("Type") == "Billing"
    select el;
foreach (XElement el in address)
    Console.WriteLine(el);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything between opening and closing tags are part of an element. To get the desired output, you need to either 1. reconstruct the element to include only the needed information :

```
foreach (XElement el in address)
{
    var newElement = new XElement(
                            el.Name.LocalName,
                            el.Attributes(),
                            el.Elements().Where(o => o.Name.LocalName != "Address")
                     );
    Console.WriteLine(newElement.ToString());
}
```

or 2. remove all unnecessary information i.e `Address` elements :

```
foreach (XElement el in address)
{
    el.Elements("Address").Remove();
    Console.WriteLine(el.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. That's a good idea. May I ask you to explain "reconstruct the element to include only the needed information"?
I think it would be a great idea as well.

Comment: @SaberJalilzadeh updated with an example for the other approach. Hope it helps

Comment: I really appreciate it. It gives a great idea

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication87
{
    namespace Linq
    {
        class Program
        {
            const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                List<string> acceptableElements = new List<string>(){"Name", "Street", "City", "State", "Zip", "Country"};

                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
                List<XElement> addresses = doc.Descendants("Address").ToList();
                XElement billing = addresses.Where(x => x.Attribute("Type").Value == "Billing").FirstOrDefault();
                addresses.Remove();
                XElement po = (XElement)doc.FirstNode;
                po.Add(billing);
            }
        }
    }


}
```